# Java web service response is encoded, so .Net can't understand it

Tags: .net, web-services, encoding

I am calling a Java web service, which returns some data.  When I look at the returned results in Fiddler, it looks something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2012 15:14:03 GMT
Server: Apache
Keep-Alive: timeout=300, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en

46f
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cre="http://www.example.org/getOrderList/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cre:getOrderListResponse1 status="success">
          <GetOrderList company="LO" OrderNumber="0423180" CustomerNumber="2150" Branch="000" customerReference="1001" orderStatus="cancelled" suspendCode=""/>
      </cre:getOrderListResponse1>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

0
```

Fiddler reports that the "Response is encoded and may need to be decoded before inspection."

I'm assuming that the 4F6 between the header and the body and the 0 end the end are making it so .Net can't process the result.

Any ideas how can I get around this?

Edited: It appears that the problem might be that I'm calling the service using HTTP 1.1, and the service is returning HTTP 1.0.  Any idea how I can force the service to call using HTTP 1.0?

Comment: It seems OK since `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. .Net should handle it without any problem. It is more like [XY-Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)

Comment: Well, .Net is having a problem.  I don't know why, just making some guesses.  The object is null in my .Net application.  Any ideas why it would be null?

Comment: Scottie, without any hint, any code i don't think I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you were exactly right, L.B.  It was an XY problem.

The problem ended up being that the namespace in the response was incorrect.

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:cre="http://www.example.org/getOrderList/">
```

needed to be

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:cre="http://www.example.org/LathamIntOE/">
```

Once this was changed in the Java service, it worked fine.